# How do I zoom in on a location using mapkit in swift 2 (xcode)

Tags: xcode, swift, location, mapkit, ios9

I am trying to zoom into a point on the map when a user inputs an address, for example, one infinite loop. I want it to zoom in to the location to the street level but I cannot for the love of God get it to zoom in. I have tried messing with the region, the span, etc. but no luck. Here is what my code looks like (I have nothing in the view did load func)... you will see i have commented out some code because I tried it and nothing happened. 
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjrFw.png) and here is what the output is on the simulator [the output on simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqYKN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you define `func` in `geocodeAddressString` closure?

How about the following code?

```
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error", error)
        }

        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
            let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0001, longitudeDelta: 0.0001)
            let coordinate = placemark.location!.coordinate
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    })
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Use `var` for span and region rather than `let`.
>
> You need to get rid of the `self` in front of `Map.setRegion`
>
> Also try a bigger number for the span coordinates something like `0.4` or `0.5`
> or you could still use `0.0001` that doesn't really matter.

`span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.4,0.4)`

```
var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: **location variable goes in here** , span = span ) 
Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the method works but for some reason (and It could just be my simulator) but when it zooms in to the location, all I see are yellow squares ( as if the actual map is not loaded yet.)  - any advice?

Comment: I  noticed that sometimes the simulator just takes a really long time to  load I had the same issue with the WatchKit;  it took me at least 10 minutes for the simulator to load. It's probably an IOS 9 bug

Comment: Thanks, just had to wait a bit! great help everyone